# how can i extract game resources made by Unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, data-extraction

I operated according to the tutorial of the following website[this is the tutorial](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_43287088/article/details/108676150), but found that the contents of the file were different from those in the tutorial. As a result, when I extracted the assets folder, there was no content I wanted to obtain

i had tried to use AssetStudio to extract game but seems it failed,there are no resources in the packet folder of this game, only these contents in the picture, how should I extract the resources inside?If I only want to extract images, do I need to unzip the obb package? Or unpack the APK package?
someone come to help me,please,thanks a lot.
[p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy5vY.png)
this is my file directory/

> 

base\assets\bin\Data\Managed